# Driver conflicts between multiple printers installed on one computer

Tags: windows-10, multi-function-printer, print-drivers

HP support are telling me it's NOT possible to have an AIO multi-function printer installed on the same computer as a Laser printer due to driver conflicts.

Is this correct?  Specifically, **is it a known fact that AIO printer drivers take over the machine in such as way that you can not add any other printers?**

*More info:*
I have had an **HP LaserJet** and **HP OfficeJet AIO** inkjet/scanner/fax installed on the same Windows 10 computer for about a year via network connection. Recently I noticed I was not able to print from the LaserJet with various errors - *depending on the software I'm printing from* - stating the printer is not installed correctly. I uninstalled both and after some trouble, re-installed the latest drivers for both. Yet I received the same error, only now from the AIO. **After calling HP support I was informed it is not possible to have multiple printers installed if one of them is an AIO multi-function printer.** This just sounds so strange to me... ? I feel like this would be a common small-business office setup no?

Comment: What are the exact error messages? And what exactly is your question?

Comment: Well, regardless of what is going on - it is completely ridiculous what they said.

Comment: @harrymc my question is simply whether it is indeed impossible to connect a laser printer and AIO inkjet to the same computer. It sounds sooo incorrect to me... but HP is essentially saying I need to get rid of one of the printers.

Comment: They can certainly be connected to the same computer. Some OSes even let you install independent drivers for each. But apparently not Windows, particularly with HP's drivers.

Comment: How are you connecting the printers to the computer (usb cable, ethernet, wifi)? Do you expect both printers to work in parallel? If you disable one of the printers in Devices and Printers, does the other work? What drivers are you using?